# Visual Studio Windows Phone 7 play sound

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a Windows Phone 7 App and am trying to play a sound.

I have the code to do it but it cannot find the file when I try to run it on the emulator.

I have added the sound file as a resource (I think)

here is the code in case it is the problem

```
PlaySound(@"Sounds\show.wav");
```

And the function

```
private void PlaySound(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(path))
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                        effect.Play();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            timerCount.Text = path;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `Build Action` on the file to `Content`.

Comment: Thanks, is always the little things you've just got to know

Comment: Every so often, I run into this problem and am stumped for ~3 hours. I think I'm going to print this out and glue it to my monitor.